# bash/readline doesn't autocomplete directory name

Tags: command-line, bash, tab-completion, readline

I have an executable in a subdirectory of the current directory:

```
~ $ ls -l src/users
-rwxr-xr-x 1 me users 1001K Nov 17 18:52 src/users*
```

I try to execute it by typing `sr` and then clicking tab. There happen to be two possibilities for completion (one directory in my home and one executable in /usr/bin/) so I'd expect bash to show them to me:

```
~ $ sr
src/ srptool
```

Instead, it completes the executable name `srptool` (ignoring the directory with my executable).

I tested with another directory name and found out that when the only possible completion is directory name, bash completes it as expected.

I experience the same behavior in bash 3.2.53 on Mac and 4.3.39 on Linux.

I remember this working before. I'm not sure whether it's a bash or a readline issue. Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try `./sr`?

Comment: @ClassStacker The problem is not that I don't know how to execute it. I am wondering why it ignores the directory in my example.

Answer (score 1):

Your `$PATH` contains either `./` or the parent directory of `src` and `srptool`.

Bash auto-completion completes commands found in your `$PATH`, so if `./` is in there and your current working directory contains executables, hitting <kbd>Tab</kbd> inside it will make Bash expand the name of whatever executables are in it.